# How to select data whose column_name data has digits only in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, numbers, row, digits

How to select row data whose column_name has digits only in PostreSQL?

Like when table has:

```
ID | Column_name
 1 | 000012
 2 | ABC001
```

The expected result on select should only be the ID 1 wherein the Column_name has only digits.

I have tried this code but does not work:

```
select *
from table
Where not Column_name like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Can anybody give me advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A regex is probably the easiest thing:

```
where column_name ~ E'^\\d+$'
```

See the [POSIX Regular Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) section of the manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `trim`:

```
 where trim(a,'0123456789') = ''
```

, but regex is probably better solution.